# Simple random vector function returns same direction more than once

Tags: python, pygame

So I made this simple function to return a random vector of magnitude 1 using pygame, basically a random vector that is then normalized (giving a direction). However, when I run a for loop calling this function, some of the directions are the same, if not just flipped 180 or smth. I'm iterating 3 times, just because if it can't do 3 random vectors, I can't trust it to do hundreds...

```
import random
import math
from pygame import Vector2

def random_direction():
    vector = Vector2(random.uniform(-10, 10), random.uniform(-10, 10))
    if vector.length() == 0:
        return vector
    else:
        return Vector2.normalize(vector)

for i in range(3):
    v = random_direction()
    print(v)
    print(math.degrees(math.atan2(v.y,v.x)))
```

Output Example:

```
[-0.481089, 0.876672]
118.75655978063934
[0.524372, 0.851489]
58.374037634092204
[-0.504321, 0.863516]
120.2862923019005
```

As you can see, the second and third are the same angle, just flipped. I've tried other PRNG's, not normalizing them, but nothing seems to change it.

Comment: what about `random.randint(-10, 10)`?

Comment: oh, I think I know, it could be that pygame uses radians

Comment: Randint gives same thing, just more limited number of angles. Also, don't worry about the last line, it just converts the vector into an angle in degrees, purely for analysis.

Comment: also, no, it seems completely fine, try running  a lot more than 3 sample and it should work fine

Comment: also there is no such thing as random for computers (maybe some scientific have this) they always have a reference so it is more or less pseudo-random, which also maybe may make it seem not so random, but I don't know, so far the examples You have provide seem to be fine, just run them a little bit more and implement in the program to know how they look, then You will see if they are random or not

Comment: no change... :(

Comment: what do You mean, what was the output? because the `random.uniform()` certainly generates pretty random numbers, I tested for a hundred cases and they seemed pretty random

Comment: have you tester random vectors though?? very nice of you btw :)

Comment: random vectors would be a logical after-product

Comment: I ran Your code for a hundred loops instead of 3, in general results were pretty much random

Comment: You appear to have a human understanding of random. Just because `[0.524372, 0.851489]` and `[-0.504321, 0.863516]` look similar, doesn't at all mean they are. A coin can be random and be heads two times in a row. A generator can be random and generate 'similar' numbers twice in a row.

Comment: It happens almost every time, besides the program above is just extracted from another program to test it. The thing is, I'm trying to shoot objects at random directions in pygame. I've done it before but somehow this time around, all the objects go in the same exact line: 45 degrees to the left... Perhaps I shoud post that.

Comment: @diegolondrina *"As you can see, the second and third are the same angle,"* - No I can't see that. There are no identically angles.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to generate a random angle in range [0, 2*PI]. Compute the vector from the angle:

```py
angle = random.uniform(0, math.PI*2)
vector = Vector2(math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle))
```

or

```py
vector = Vector2(1, 0).rotate_rad(random.uniform(0, math.PI*2))
```

Comment: [0.50612, 0.862463]
59.59424561143356
[0.926421, -0.37649]
-22.116460257976787
[0.941912, 0.33586]
19.624856781257044 same thing for some reason...

Comment: Sorry, but this directions are different. What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Implemented the function inside a class for objects which I wanted to give that random direction and created n objects inside a for-loop. So implementing it as an object attribute alongside others instead of finding a random vector 3 times in a row fixes it...