# Pygame: How to shoot objects in random directions?

Tags: python, pygame

Objects all go off in the same line (45 degrees to the left)...
When I extract the random_direction function to test it by itself, it gives the same vectors just flipped 180 or the x is the same and y is the same but negative... stuff like that.

```
import pygame
import os
import math
import random
from pygame.math import Vector2

def random_direction():
    vector = Vector2(random.uniform(-max_speed, max_speed), random.uniform(-max_speed, max_speed))
    if vector.length() == 0:
        return vector
    else:
        return Vector2.normalize(vector)


def scaled(vector, scale):
    if vector.length() == 0:
        return vector
    else:
        return Vector2.normalize(vector) * scale


def clamped(vector, limit):
    if vector.length() <= limit or vector.length() == 0:
        return vector
    else:
        return Vector2.normalize(vector) * limit


def shoot():
    for i in range(len(boids)):
        boids[i]['velocity'] = boids[i]['desired_direction'] * max_speed
        boids[i]['boid'].x += boids[i]['velocity'].x
        boids[i]['boid'].y += boids[i]['velocity'].x
        # if boids[i]['boid'].x >= WIDTH:
        #     boids[i]['boid'].x = 0
        # elif boids[i]['boid'].x <= 0:
        #     boids[i]['boid'].x = WIDTH
        # elif boids[i]['boid'].y >= HEIGHT:
        #     boids[i]['boid'].y = 0
        # elif boids[i]['boid'].y <= 0:
        #     boids[i]['boid'].y = HEIGHT

def draw_window():
    WIN.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # for i in range(n):
    #     rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image_scaled, math.degrees(math.atan2(boids[i]['velocity'].x, boids[i]['velocity'].y)) +180)
    #     WIN.blit(rot_image, (boids[i]['boid'].x - int(rot_image.get_width()/2), boids[i]['boid'].y - int(rot_image.get_height()/2))) #########
    for i in range(len(boids)):
        WIN.blit(image_scaled, (boids[i]['boid'].x, boids[i]['boid'].y))
    pygame.display.update()


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1440, 720 #1680, 990
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Sim')
FPS = 60

image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'long_fish.png'))
image_width, image_height = 40, 40
image_scaled = pygame.transform.scale(image, (image_width, image_height))
#boid = pygame.Rect(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, image_width, image_height)
max_speed = 10 #2
steer_strength = 0.04 #2
wander_strength = 0.4 #0.2
# desired_direction = Vector2(0, 0)
# velocity = Vector2(0, 0)
# shoot_direction = random_direction()
n = 30
boids = []
for i in range(n):
    boids.append({'boid': pygame.Rect(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, image_width, image_height),
                  'desired_direction': random_direction(),
                  'velocity': Vector2(0,0)})


def main():

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        shoot()

        draw_window()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've made things like this before on pygame and they work but I'm not sure why they do and this doesn't.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free debugging site. Please make an MCVE, not a code dump.

Comment: Vector values themselves seem completely randomized

Comment: The angles seem to be random too, tho python uses radians so You should be aware of that

Comment: Also, your vectors are random but not uniformly distributed

Comment: @MadPhysicist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994675/simple-random-vector-function-returns-same-direction-more-than-once

Comment: @diegolondrina. That does not alter the fact that OP is generating vectors outside the max_speed circle.

Answer (score 0):

Your vector generator generates with bounds of a square:
[image]

because of the way you set it up. You then normalize the vector, putting whatever it raised into the bounding circle. Because of this method, values nearer to the corners are more likely to be chosen. From the origin to the edge, there is a distance of one. From the origin to the corner, there is a distance of 1.41 . Thus, values that normalize to a corner are more likely to be chosen

This can give you the impression of not having truly random values, as some values pop up more frequently than others.

The way around this is to generate an already normalized vector, py choosing a point from a circle.

The best way to do this is to generate an angle, *in radians*. Ex:

```
>>> angle = math.radians(random.randint(0, 360))
```

Then, use some basic trigonometry to turn that angle into a point

```
>>> x = math.cos(angle)
>>> y = math.sin(angle)
```

The tuple `(x, y)` should be an unbiased value, that is as random as your pseudorandom (how computers do random, it's actually a big complex equation that generates a value really close to random, but it actually isn't) generator will get.

Implementing this into your code:

```
def random_direction():
    a = math.radians(random.randint(0, 360))
    return pygame.Vector2(math.cos(a), math.sin(a))
```

Comment: OP seems to want to generate random velocity too.

Comment: Wait... I think you're completely right about generating inside the bounds of a square, but it still does the same thing with your function...  Your explanation blew my mind though thanks.